# Using Touch ID for Server Side Authentication in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, encryption, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to implement sever side authentication based on the finger print of the iOS user. I came across a way to do this in this article - https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/ios-touch-id-swift of leveraging Auth0, but how can we generate key pairs in ionic ?

Atleast in android we can get a token back - https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth#module_fingerprintauth.decrypt

Does not seem to be the case with iOS ? Any help or direction is appreciated.